# I have used cacheable false for one block on home page but my whole page uncacheable , how can i prevent it

Tags: magento2

I have used cacheable="false" for 1 block, but varnish cache is not working due to this as whole page is uncaheable now. please suggest me alternate for this.

Comment: please add code

Comment: sorry but didn't get your point

Comment: post your xml file code here.